# SQL Join with where clause in joined table

Tags: php, mysql, join

world.

I have two tables here called drivers and checkin.
the d_id field of the checkin table is holds the id of an entry in the drivers table.

In my query, im trying to join the tables and do a where condition on the joined table.

So far i have this query(i haven't been able to join the tables, the where part on the joined table comes after i achieve this)

```
SELECT checkin.id, checkin.d_id, checkin.place, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(8.9551889) ) * cos( radians( lati ) )
* cos( radians( longi ) - radians(76.9902276) ) + sin( radians(8.9551889) ) * sin(radians(lati)) ) ) AS distance
FROM checkin WHERE status != 1
INNER JOIN drivers ON drivers.id = checkin.d_id
HAVING distance < 10 
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

This query works without the inner join, but i'm not really sure what im doing wrong here. If anybody can point it out, that'd be helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: if you use where clause then no need to write "Having".   you are not using group by  so having and where clause working same.  also use where clause after inner join.  --- if your drivers table not return data than after be you want result to use left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `where` clause after `inner join`:

```
SELECT checkin.id, checkin.d_id, checkin.place, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(8.9551889) ) * cos( radians( lati ) )
* cos( radians( longi ) - radians(76.9902276) ) + sin( radians(8.9551889) ) * sin(radians(lati)) ) ) AS distance
FROM checkin 
INNER JOIN drivers ON drivers.id = checkin.d_id
WHERE status != 1
HAVING distance < 10 
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Alternative query:

```
 SELECT checkin.id, checkin.d_id, checkin.place, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(8.9551889) ) * cos( radians( lati ) )
    * cos( radians( longi ) - radians(76.9902276) ) + sin( radians(8.9551889) ) * sin(radians(lati)) ) ) AS distance
    FROM (select *from checkin where status!=1) checkin
    INNER JOIN drivers ON drivers.id = checkin.d_id
    HAVING distance < 10 
    ORDER BY distance
    LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Comment: Thanks, the query runs without error, however its not returning the data from the drivers table.

Comment: @HaiderAli Are these fields both correct: `checkin.id, checkin.d_id`?

Comment: @aendeerei i figured it out, i had to mention the fields i wanted from the joined table in the select statement

Comment: @HaiderAli Perfect. Good luck then.